# Vue.js anchor to div within the same component

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm developing a Vue.js application and I'm having trouble to link an anchor to a certain div within a component.

I have the following anchor:

```
<a href="#porto" class="porto-button">Porto, Portugal</a>
```

and the following div:

```
<div id="porto" class="fl-porto">
```

I'm using vue-router in hash mode.

The problem is, whenever I click the "porto-button" it will redirect me to the "home" page ( ' / ' )

I'm using Vue.js 1.X and I tried using history mode (URL without the hashbang) but it gives me a `cannot GET '/page'` error upon refreshing a page.

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do about this?

Comment: I think just take the '#' out of your id? Should just be `<div id="porto" class="fl-porto">`, no?

Comment: I did that but to no avail. That's the first thing I tried to do actually but I am up to anything at this point. (I'll edit the question nonetheless)

Comment: Put a named anchor tag inside your div? `<a name="porto">`, then your `a href="#porto">` should work.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see you were in hash mode. If you switch to history mode, it should work, but you'll need a catchall route, per: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode

Comment: I tried using history mode too. However, the link breaks with `cannot GET /page` whenever I refresh the page I am in

Comment: This could be helpful
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379731/vuejs-scroll-to-section-from-different-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379731/vuejs-scroll-to-section-from-different-route)

Comment: This could be helpful
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379731/vuejs-scroll-to-section-from-different-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379731/vuejs-scroll-to-section-from-different-route)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because you are using router in hash mode, you will not be able to scroll that easily because scrolling to `/#something` will actually redirect you to 'something' page.

You will have to emulate scrolling behaviour on your own, try doing something like that:

```
//P.S. the code is written for Vue 2.
//You will have to adjust it to Vue 1.

//Your view:
<a class="porto-button" @click="scrollMeTo('porto')">Porto, Portugal</a>
...
<div ref="porto" class="fl-porto">
```

```
//Your code:
methods: {
  scrollMeTo(refName) {
    var element = this.$refs[refName];
    var top = element.offsetTop;

    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
}
```

How it works:

1. Set the references through `ref` attribute to the element you would like to scroll to;
2. Write a function that will programmatically set `window.scrollY` to the `top` of the referenced element.
3. Job is done :)

**Update 1:**

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5k4ptmqg/4/

**Update 2:**

Seems that in Vue 1 `ref="name"` looked like `el:name` [(docs)](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#vm-els), here is an updated example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5y3pkoyz/2/

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this. It is not working. Is this compatible with Vue 1.X or is it exclusive to Vue 2.X??

Comment: it is not exclusive to vue2, create jsfiddle with your tryings @fmlopes

Comment: It really seems to be something related to the Vue build version. Because it works when using 2.0.1 and not with 1.0.7. https://jsfiddle.net/frankml/5y3pkoyz/1/

The button press returns "element is undefined"

Comment: @fmlopes have added a new example for vue 1 (Update 2). Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is the correct answer. I tried in the 1.X build and it worked. Then updated to the 2.X build and it worked as well.

Answer (score 19):

Another method is to use "scrollIntoView()"

So, euvl's code still stands, except you would change the method slightly:

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      methods: {
        goto(refName) {
            var element = this.$els[refName];
          element.scrollIntoView();
        }
      }
    })
```

If you wanted to get fancy and make the scroll smooth, you can even add the following:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Note that this will need a polyfill for older browsers.

Comment: In VueJS 2 replace `this.$els` with `this.$refs` to make this work.

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me

```
<router-link to="#leaders">Leaders</router-link>
```

or dynamic

```
<router-link :to="`#${subMenuItem.linkTarget}`" class="page-submenu-list__link">
                    {{subMenuItem.linkTitle}}
                </router-link>
```

in router

```
routes:[],
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    //https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html
    if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash }
        } else if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
  }
```

Comment: This only seems to work the first time - if I scroll up and click again it does not scroll me down to the correct div

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution is to use the `v-scroll-to` directive ([webpage](https://vue-scrollto.netlify.app/), [github](https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollTo)).
I find this solution to be clean, simple, flexible and effective.  To use:

1. Install it:

   ```
   npm install --save vue-scrollto
   ```
2. Have Vue 'use' it:

   ```
   var VueScrollTo = require('vue-scrollto');
   Vue.use(VueScrollTo)
   ```
3. Apply it as a directive in your Vue component's template:

   ```
   <a href="#" v-scroll-to="'#element'">Scroll to #element</a>

   <div id="element">
     Hi. I'm #element.
   </div>
   ```
4. Or apply it programmatically in your Vue component's methods:

   ```
   this.$scrollTo('#element', 500, { easing: 'ease-in-out' })
   ```
5. Or apply it programmatically in your Vuex actions:

   ```
   import { scrollTo } from 'vue-scrollto'

   scrollTo('#element', 500, { easing: 'ease-in-out' })
   ```

Another solution, if you're already using Vuetify, you may prefer to use [Vuetify's built-in programmatic scrolling method](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/scroll/), `$vuetify.goTo()`:

```
<v-btn @click="$vuetify.goTo('#element', {duration: 500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'})">
  Scroll to #element
</v-btn>

<div id="element">
  Hi. I'm #element.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. vue-scrollto didn't do what i expected it to but the vuetify solution was the magic

Answer (score 3):

If you set a `ref="something"` on an element, you could also use this oneliner with `@click`:

```
<a @click="$refs.something.$el.scrollIntoView()">
    Go to something
</a>
```