# VueJS scroll to section from different route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to scroll to an anchor on a page using Vue and Vue Router (with history mode).

When on the index page, the scroll behaviour works as expected by jumping to the section.

However, when I am another page, it loads the index page at the top and not where the anchor is pointing to.

I’m sure it’s a very simple thing but can’t get my head round it!

Any help is appreciated!

**My router index:**

```js
export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    } else {
      return {x: 0, y: 0}
    }
  },

  mode: 'history',
  routes: [ ... ]
})
```

**My Navigation:**

```html
<router-link @click.native="closeNav" to="/#enter">Enter</router-link>
<router-link @click.native="closeNav" to="/#prizes">Prizes</router-link>
<router-link @click.native="closeNav" to="/#faqs">FAQ</router-link>
<router-link @click.native="closeNav" to="/contactus">Contact</router-link>
```

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried async scrolling? its laid out in the docs but i'm not seeing it in your snippet. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Answer (score 13):

## Vue Router v3.x

This is a bit of an old question and OP has almost surely found a solution already, but for anyone running into this problem, this should do the trick:

```html
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Homepage', hash: '#enter' }">Enter</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Homepage', hash: '#prizes' }">Prizes</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Homepage', hash: '#faqs' }">FAQ</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Contact' }">Contact</router-link>
```

This should allow you to have these links accessible from other views/components, and when clicked will redirect you to the named route (Homepage in this case), and scroll to the hash specified (#enter, #prizes, #faqs).

In addition to the router code snippet in the question, you can add smooth scrolling using the native `window.scrollTo` method:

```js
    export default new Router({
      routes: [],
      mode: 'history',
      scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
          return window.scrollTo({ 
            top: document.querySelector(to.hash).offsetTop, 
            behavior: 'smooth' 
          })
        } else {
          return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
      }
    })
```

## Update for Vue Router v4.x

You write your `router-link`s the same, but you can write the scroll behavior and element selection a bit neater now. [From the docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior)

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Error: ```offsetTop of undefined```

Comment: @RaviWadhwani If you're getting that error, make sure the hash you're defining in the to attribute's hash key is on the page you're navigating to...

For example, if you have a router link like his:
`<router-link :to="{ name: 'Homepage', hash: '#faq' }"></router-link>`

Then make sure the Homepage has an element with an id of "faq", like this:
`<div id="faq"> ... </div>`

If you're not sure if that page is going to have that hash (for whatever reason), then you may need to alter the code in the answer to check that `document.querySelector(to.hash)` exists first to avoid that error.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `scrollIntoView()` instead of `window.scrollTo()`

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [],
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return document.querySelector(to.hash).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    } else {
      return savedPosition || { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
})
```