# Vue router history mode but when i use hash on url it reloads the page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue router and have already set mode to history. My app works fine except that when i try to use hash (#) in url in order to scroll the page to an element in the same page (eg: #information) the page reloads (meaning it re-requests data from my backend). I think the router thinks the page has changed and tries to load that page.

EDIT: The page does not really reload. It re-fetches data from by backend. I understand this as a reload though.

I tried googling but all i get is how to use history mode. Maybe i am searching the wrong way.

Any clues on how to fix this?

Here is my route:

```
{
            path: '/p/:idormpn/:slug',
            name: 'Productpage',
            component: Productpage
        }
```

Here is an example of what is happening:
https://www.e-checkout.gr/p/63529/dermatina-anatomika-pedila-mavro

Thanks!

Comment: You have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645964/vue-js-anchor-to-div-within-the-same-component

Comment: Sorry but the answer you are suggesting is talking about trying to scroll while using hash mode... I am trying to do this while using history mode. The hash should not be a problem while on history mode. Am i talking nonsense here? Please guide

Comment: For you it should work from the box then. Can you create simple codepen to simulate this?

Comment: How are you getting the new URL - by clicking on a link, by typing it in the address bar, or by setting `window.location.hash` programmatically ? The browser is expected to reload the page only when you type an URL into the address bar.

Comment: The url is a link on the page's html like so: <a href="#information">Info</a>

Comment: @IVOGELOV i am clicking on  a link hardcoded in html

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut No codepen but i can show you the project page here:
https://www.e-checkout.gr/p/63529/dermatina-anatomika-pedila-mavro

Comment: Hey guys! Any ideas on how to solve this issue?