# vue-smooth-scroll redirect vuejs link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

i use this package for my website, build with **vuejs**.

On my navbar, i have "About", who redirect me on my div "#about", on my main page "/".

```
<a href="#boxes-area" v-smooth-scroll="{ duration: 1000, offset: -50, updateHistory: false }" class="nav-link">Services</a>
```

But, i have a nanother different page, "Contact", and if im on this page, the link "href="#boxes-area" not working, it's normal.
But if i change that :

```
<a href="#boxes-area" v-smooth-scroll="{ duration: 1000, offset: -50, updateHistory: false }" class="nav-link">Services</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/#boxes-area" class="nav-link">Services</a>
```

The redirection work, but without "smooth effect".

If i do that

```
<a href="/#boxes-area" v-smooth-scroll="{ duration: 1000, offset: -50, updateHistory: false }" class="nav-link">Services</a>
```

Nothing work, no redirection and no effects.

I use this plugin, and they dont talk about that :
https://github.com/ocordeiro/vue-smooth-scroll

---

i tried too with a router link, but doesnt work too, same problems.

```
<li class="nav-item"><router-link to="/#boxes-area" v-smooth-scroll="{ duration: 1000, offset: -50, updateHistory: false }" class="nav-link">Services</router-link></li>
```

---

Someone can help me pls ?

Comment: are you using [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)? If not, you have to scroll programatically to the anchor.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648061/11219314).

Comment: @Kodiak i use the history mode yes :/