# how to use target child div without id in href?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am using the href attribute to target slider in wrapper div, but in Vue it pushes the routing of that id href, is that any alternative without using href to target slider in div by id?

The href in Vue is gonna be click to new route of that id, that is why i find alternative to disable it or use another way to target the box?

```js
const slide = document.querySelector(".slides")

slide.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.scrollLeft)
  const slide2 = document.querySelector("#slide-2")
  console.log(slide2.offsetWidth)
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /*
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  */
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.slides>div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.slides>div:target {
  /*     transform: scale(0.8); */
}

.author-info {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.author-info a {
  color: white;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider>a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.slider>a:active {
  top: 1px;
}

.slider>a:focus {
  background: #000;
}


/* Don't need button navigation */

@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider>a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74abe2, #5563de);
  font-family: "Ropa Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js anchor to div within the same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645964/vue-js-anchor-to-div-within-the-same-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace **href** by a function with [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

I edited in your demo:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shironvn/pen/XWRoqRY?editors=1010)

```
  <a onclick="srollToPosition(1)">1</a>
    <a onclick="srollToPosition(2)">2</a>
    <a onclick="srollToPosition(3)">3</a>
    <a onclick="srollToPosition(4)">4</a>

  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const srollToPosition = (slideNumber) => {
  const slide = document
    .getElementById(`slide-${slideNumber}`)
    .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest" });
};
```

Comment: this is useful for make button arrow right and left also i bet, but is that possible to use `scrollIntoView` to jump click right to per 3 divs/box ?

Comment: I see that it's able to do with button number in your demo

Comment: but i found on edge and safari ios doesnt support for scrollIntoView :(, is that anh alternative ??